# JSfiddle Create button that will disappear when clicked

Tags: javascript, button

I would like to create a button that will, when clicked, disappear and then start displaying the time with the set interval of 2 seconds. I am trying to modify this code to do that:

```
var App = {
    refreshDataRegularly: function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://rahulv.com/test/ajax/interval/index.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('.response-area').html(data);
                }
            });        
        }, 2000);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    App.refreshDataRegularly();
});
```

How can I accomplish this?
Thank you

Comment: You need a button, an event handler for the click event, and code to hide the button and execute your function.

Comment: Without being rude, you would make a button, and then have it disappear when clicked. For a more robust answer explain what you have already tried, what has worked and what hasn't. In short, show more effort than that you copied and pasted some skeleton code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind a `click` event handler.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  App.refreshDataRegularly();
});
```

For hidding the button, you should use `hide()` method.

```js
var App = {
   refreshDataRegularly: function(){
     setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax({
               url: 'http://rahulv.com/test/ajax/interval/index.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('.response-area').html(data);
                 }
          });        
    }, 2000);
  }
};
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  App.refreshDataRegularly();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="response-area"></div>
```

Comment: While it was not me, it was likely because you answered a homework question, without letting the asker put in any actual effort.

Comment: This is actually not a homework question, I was simply curious. I was exploring JSfiddle trying to learn more about Javascript and I ran across this example and I was curious about how to modify it to display what I wanted to display. I am still new to Javascript.

Comment: @Chris , don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.